# "Transform" in Unity Engine returning error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

Using Unity 2019.4.8f1 and Visual Studio 2019.

I'm learning some coding through a Udemy course and building a camera movement script for a top-down RPG that moves similar to the original Legend of Zelda. I'm receiving these two errors:

> Assets\Scripts\CameraMotor.cs(16,25): error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'postition' and no accessible extension method 'postition' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)<

> Assets\Scripts\CameraMotor.cs(30,25): error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'postition' and no accessible extension method 'postition' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)<

When comparing my screen to the instructor screen, I see that the term "Transform" isn't changing color, so I'm wondering if this piece of code doesn't exist in the same format any more in the current version of Unity (he's using 2017, I believe).

This is the code I'm using:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform lookAt;
    public float boundX = 0.15f;
    public float boundY = 0.05f;
```

Any suggestions for what's going on here?

Comment: It will be easier to provide help if you add the parts of the file that are causing errors to your question. My guess is you should be using an instance of `Transform` rather than the class itself.

Comment: `position` not `postition`

Comment: It's a simple typo ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So Now When You Try To Access Something From A Class You Need To Spell It Properly, So What Did Wrong Is That You Have Misspelled The Transform's Definition `position` , and your errors show that, you are using `postition` instead of  `position`, Where Ever You Want To Access The Property Of Any Class You Need To Use The Variable Name And Then The Dot Followed By The Property Name, So The Fix Is Is 
**Where Ever You Have Used Following Code:**

`lookAt.postition`

**Replace It With This**

`lootAt.position`